# How can I rescue my boarding drone from the final boss?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The image probably speaks for itself.

[image: The first stage of the final boss in FTL; a deactivated boarding drone is occupying the isolated gatling missing launcher area.]

Is there any way I can entice my boarding drone to come back? If I deactivate/reactive it with power allocation it just goes to sleep and wakes up. It can't go anywhere else and it can't do anything useful where it is.

Comment: At least it hit the missiles.

Comment: @aslum: Actually, it managed to hit the missiles I had already blown up. :(

Comment: That is AWESOME. I thought it was going to be a request to recover the drone part, but that is *fantastic*.

Comment: Ouch. That bites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wow, that's an interesting case.

I'm going to guess that you can actively fire on the room with ships' weapons and then destroy the drone, which would ready it for re-deployment.  It's not a fast solution though, and there exists the real possibility that you will have destroyed the enemy before you "free up" the droid.